# Python, Elementium. Подскажите почему по-умолчанию после теста не закрывает браузер?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Python, Elementium (обёртка вокруг Selenium)
Подскажите почему по-умолчанию после теста не закрывает браузер? (тест проходит, но окно браузера остаётся и при последующих тестах, окна висят)
И как это исправить.

Сама инициализация драйвера проходит так:

```
s = SeElements(webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вызвать закрытие [так](https://github.com/actmd/elementium/blob/438d580dd9395b75c8d5a37251b4857718faa2dc/examples/simple/simple.py#L35):

```
s = SeElements(webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
...
s.browser.quit()
```